# how to iterate over a list of strings and modify each of them based on another list Python

Tags: python, list

Hello everyone I'm quite new in programming, I have this issue:

I want to modify strings in a list, more precisely, erase a substring if this substring is present in another list of strings. I have tried this solution but doesn't work.

```
res=[]
a=['ACTGACTG','ACTGAAA','AGGGAGGG','Ernesto','AAGGACTG','X']
b=['ACTG','AA','X']
for x in a:
    for y in b:
        if y in x:
            res.append(x.replace(y,''))

print(res)
```

Output:

```
['', 'AAA', 'ACTGA', 'AAGG', 'GGACTG', '']
```

Now there few problems in this

1. I'd like 'Ernesto' and 'AGGGAGGG' to be present in the result even if nothing matches in b
2. ACTG in the first output matches 2 times so is erased both of the time and I'd want to be erased one time so the desired output would be
3. X is erased but I got an empty string, I would like just not to have the entry

**The desired output would be like**

`['ACTG', 'A', 'AGGGAGGG', 'Ernesto', 'GG']`

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track just add the number of times you want to replace the old substring with the new substring.

Then just add the new string only if the string is not empty

```
for x in a:
    for y in b:
        x = x.replace(y,'',1)
    if x:
        res.append(x)
```

Comment: Why have the extra if statement? It seems unnecessary. Other than that it is just my answer.

Comment: To avoid empty strings

Comment: other if. The ```if y in x:```

Comment: because I haven't slept well